# rebuild yum index on aws s3

Tags: linux, yum, amazon-s3, repository

I am trying to rebuild yum repo on aws S3 after adding new packages.

Here are few commands I am trying, but it is not helping.

```
[root@chucks ~]$ createrepo --baseurl http://rpmcopy.xxxxx.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com /repodata/   --update

Saving Primary metadata
Saving file lists metadata
Saving other metadata
Generating sqlite DBs
Sqlite DBs complete
```

How do I give a path from S3? /repodata/ path is not relevent I believe.

All my pkgs are under bucket s3://rpmcopy.xxxxx.com/. And repodata dir is under s3://rpmcopy.xxxxx.com/repodata

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. What you can do, however, is to use something like s3fs to "mount" the s3 bucket locally.

---

***EDIT (this part of the answer comes from a comment by the author of the question):***

> I achieved it by s3cmd sync the repo to my localmachine, build the repo and synced it back.
>
> Note: Before sync back to s3, remove `repo.xml` (from the `repodata` directory) on s3, otherwise changes are not refelected.
>
> `s3cmd sync s3://rpmcopy.xxxx.com/ . --skip-existing`
>
> `createrepo .`
>
> `s3cmd sync . s3://rpmcopy.xxxx.com/ --skip-existing`

Comment: I tried s3 bucket locally, but it failed with 'Transport endpoint is not connected'. I gave up.

Comment: I achieved it by s3cmd sync the repo to my localmachine, build †he repo and synced it back.  Note: Before sync back to s3, remove repo.xml (repodata directory) on s3 otherwise changes are not refelected.

s3cmd sync s3://rpmcopy.xxxx.com/ . --skip-existing
createrepo .
s3cmd sync . s3://rpmcopy.xxxx.com/ --skip-existing